# SQL Update trigger doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a problem with the programming of an Update trigger. I want to create a trigger that copies the row I edited in a new row with the new data and a new ID. The old row should be the same with just a flag change from 0 to 1.

The table look like this:

```
ID      Artikelname  PREIS        UPDATE_DATE          FLAG
1       Tomatoe      3            14.06.2012 16:00     0
2       Apple        1,5          12.05.2012 14:45     0
```

When I change the price of the first row, the table should look like this:

```
ID      Artikelname  PREIS        UPDATE_DATE          FLAG
1       Tomatoe      3            14.06.2012 16:00     1
2       Apple        1,5          12.05.2012 14:45     0
1       Tomatoe      2            13.07.2012 10:45     0
```

Here is my trigger so far:

```
USE [TestDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Produkt_Update]
ON [dbo].[Produkt]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @ID int
    DECLARE @Artikelname nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @Preis numeric
    DECLARE @Flag numeric
    DECLARE @max_id int

    SET @ID = (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
    SET @Artikelname = (SELECT Artikelname FROM inserted)
    SET @Preis = (SELECT Preis FROM inserted)
    SET @Flag = (SELECT Flag FROM inserted)
    SET @max_id = (SELECT MAX(ID) from dbo.Produkt)


    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Produkt ON
    INSERT INTO dbo.Produkt
    (ID,Artikelname,Preis)
    values (@max_id+1,@Artikelname,@Preis)
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Produkt OFF

    UPDATE dbo.Produkt
    SET Flag = 1
    WHERE ID=@ID
END
```

With my trigger I can create the new row but the price on the first row sill changes. I don't know how to handle this. Could you help me please?

Comment: Could it be because it's an after update trigger which will fire after the update on the record has been done? An before update trigger doesn't exist, but you could try with an instead of trigger I believe. With this your sql statement is 'replaced' by the contents of the trigger

Comment: One main problem: you seem to expect that `Inserted` will always contain just a single row. This is **NOT** the case! If your `UPDATE` statement updates 10 rows, then `Inserted` will contain 10 rows and your statements like `SET @ID = (SELECT ID FROM inserted)` will fail miserably.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this and let me know

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Produkt_Update]
   ON [dbo].[Produkt]
   AFTER  UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 SET  NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @MAX_ID INT;
    SELECT @MAX_ID=MAX(ID) FROM [Produkt];

    declare @tmp Table(ID  int,     Artikelname  varchar(200),
    PREIS varchar(200),UPDATE_DATE datetime,      FLAG bit)

    insert into @tmp
    select ID,Artikelname,PREIS,UPDATE_DATE,1 [flag] from deleted;

    delete T from [Produkt] T JOIN @tmp I
    ON T.ID=I.ID

SET IDENTITY_INSERT   [Produkt] ON
INSERT INTO [Produkt] (ID,Artikelname,PREIS,UPDATE_DATE,FLAG)
SELECT @MAX_ID+ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) [ID],Artikelname,PREIS,GETDATE(),0 
FROM INSERTED
union all
select * from @tmp

 SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Produkt OFF
 SET  NOCOUNT OFF;
END;
```

Comment: i get this error: Error 8101 An explicit value for the identity column in table can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Comment: @ErayGeveci: If ID is an identity column , you have to SET IDENTITY_INSERT   [Produkt] ON.. Now I have updated my query.please check

Comment: it works, thank you very much. could you explain your code a little bit?

Comment: There are two system called inserted and deleted which is accessible only within a trigger.Both these tables have the same structure as the base table. when you update a row ,the old record will be available on deleted table and the new record will be available on inserted table. What I am doing is 1. delete the record from the table which is updated 2. insert one record from inserted table to the actual table with a new Id 3.Insert one record from deleted table as it is

Comment: can i ask you another question? i tested it on another database and i get an error after editing: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint. how can i use your solution without delete. is that possible?

Comment: @ErayGeveci: I will try to find another way without delete

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the price (preis) from the deleted table, not the inserted table

Comment: i tried this, now i have the old price in the new row. and the new price is in the edited row. i need the opposite

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
 SET @ID = (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
```

with

```
SET @ID = (SELECT ID FROM deleted)
```

Comment: when i change the price of a product it still saves the changed value